# I need only letters in brackets

Tags: pascal

I need to write only letters in brackets() if  first string is Hello1 World the second must be (Hello)1 (World) but i have (Hello)1() (World) i figured out have to make digits not in brackets() bet after digit is bracket() that i dont need.
How to fix this here is my code:

```
program task2;
uses crt;
var str,name:string;
str2:^string;
i:integer;

begin
clrscr;


writeln('Enter string!');
writeln;

readln(str);
writeln;

New(str2);
str2^:='';
name:='';

for i:=1 to length(str) do
 if ((str[i]=' ') or (str[i]>='0') and (str[i]<='9')) then
               begin
                 str2^:=str2^+'('+name+')'+str[i];
                 name:='';
               end
            else name:=name+str[i];
str2^:=str2^+'('+name+')';

writeln('First string: ',str);
writeln('String length is ',length(str));
writeln;
writeln('Second string: ',str2^);
writeln('String length is ',length(str2^));

readln;
end.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that you append "name" even when "name" is null. 
Just add `if length(name)>0` like this:

```
program task2;
uses crt;
var str,name:string;
str2:^string;
i:integer;

begin
clrscr;


writeln('Enter string!');
writeln;

readln(str);
writeln;

New(str2);
str2^:='';
name:='';

for i:=1 to length(str) do
 if ((str[i]=' ') or ((str[i]>='0') and (str[i]<='9'))) then
   if (length(name)>0) then     
               begin
                 str2^:=str2^+'('+name+')'+str[i];
                 name:='';
               end
             else
            else name:=name+str[i];
str2^:=str2^+'('+name+')';

writeln('First string: ',str);
writeln('String length is ',length(str));
writeln;
writeln('Second string: ',str2^);
writeln('String length is ',length(str2^));

readln;
end.
```